# OpenCV build error in visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I trying to display a histogram of an image

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

  /**
   * @function main
   */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat src, dst;

 /// Load image
 src = imread("img.jpg", 1 );

  if( !src.data )
    { return -1; }

  // Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
  vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
  split( src, bgr_planes );

  /// Establish the number of bins
  int histSize = 256;

  /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
  float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
  const float* histRange = { range };

  bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

  Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;

  /// Compute the histograms:
  calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
  calcHist( &bgr_planes[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
  calcHist( &bgr_planes[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );

 // Draw the histograms for B, G and R
  int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
  int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );

  Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );

 /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]
  normalize(b_hist, b_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
  normalize(g_hist, g_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
  normalize(r_hist, r_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

 /// Draw for each channel
 for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
{
    line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                   Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                   Scalar( 255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
     line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                   Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                   Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
    line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                   Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                   Scalar( 0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0  );
}

 /// Display
 namedWindow("calcHist Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow("calcHist Demo", histImage );
 waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

but I got this error,when I try to build it,so please if you could help it's will be great ;)

```
 error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu "void __cdecl cv::calcHist(class cv::Mat const *,int,int const *,class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat &,int,int const *,float const * *,bool,bool)" (?calcHist@cv@@YAXPBVMat@1@HPBHABV21@AAV21@H1PAPBM_N5@Z)
```

I had already tested the configuration and I can display a sample image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, you need to put the following libraries to your project's properties, i.e. `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`:

```
opencv_imgproc.lib
opencv_highgui.lib
```

To be more clear, if you're using **OpenCV 2.4.8** in **Debug** mode, you should put the following two libs:

```
opencv_imgproc248d.lib
opencv_highgui248d.lib
```